# Unable to keep first accordion open by default in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have collapsible accordion [here](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/63563ou5/), it is working fine with static data. Now I have linked this to database and i am trying to fetch data from database. Following is the code that i have done till now in codeingiter,

View:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <?php if($student): ?>
        <?php foreach($student as $per_student): ?> 
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $per_student->id; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            <?php echo $per_student->name; ?>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="<?php echo $per_student->id; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <div class="panel-body"> 
                        <?php echo $per_student->description; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>     
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

It is fetching the data properly, however all the accordion are closed by default but i wish that the first accordion should remain open by default and rest of them should remain closed. After that the user can open and close any accordin according to his/her own wish
Can anyone please tell how i can do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have an index count for the foreach then you could have use that to set the in class for the first iteration. The following uses $key => $per_student which will set $key as the index number.

```
 <?php foreach($student as $key => $per_student): ?>
```

Then its a case of checking if $key == 0 and if so - add the in clas which causes hte panel to be open.

```
    <div id="<?php echo $per_student->id; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse 
      <?php if($key === 0){echo "in";} ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
           <div class="panel-body"> 
             <?php echo $per_student->description; ?>
           </div> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved with jQuery by below code.

```
$(".panel-collapse").each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).addClass(index == 0 ? "in" : "");
});
```

In action:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel-collapse").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).addClass(index == 0 ? "in" : "");
  });
  $('a[role="button"]:first').removeClass('collapsed'); //This will fix the icon to show 'V' (open status);
});
```

```css
#accordion .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
}

#accordion .panel-title>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#accordion .panel-title>a.accordion-toggle::before,
#accordion a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before {
  content: "\e113";
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#accordion .panel-title>a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before,
#accordion a.collapsed[data-toggle="collapse"]::before {
  content: "\e114";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="phttps://jsfiddle.net/learner001/63563ou5/#forkanel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                      Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                      Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```